# QGIS 2.12 attribute table update question

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, editing, qgis-2.12

[image]

I'm trying to fill in a whole lot of cells in the same column of an attribute table all at once using the field calculator. Am I on the right track with the following expression?

```
"Author"  || example text
```

I have tried `" "`, `' '` and `( )`, none of which seem to get the result I'm hoping for.

Comment: Can you provide more details ? Which column do you have, which type (integer, text, float, date) and what do you expect.

Comment: I have two columns one being Description and the other being Author. Both are text types. I was hoping to be able to fill all of the author ones via the field calculator to save me having to enter it 489 times.

Comment: `"Author" || 'example text'`

Comment: Do you want to use the "description" field ? Can you show us what you want in the "author" field ? (description + 'some text' or just 'some text')

Comment: I enter that text with my name but the ok button remains greyed out. Do I need to remove spaces?

Comment: I am using the description field to display the name of the town with the author field being my name. 

eg

Description Town name  Author myname

Comment: Do you want to update an existing field or do you want to create a new one ? Be sure that your layer is on edit mode.
"description" || ':' || "author"
What is the error or what is not right ?

Comment: Perhaps include a screenshot? :)

Comment: What I want to do is populate the author field via the field calculator without having to enter the information manually 400 odd times.

Comment: We understood that you would like to the field calculator, I will never edit 5 rows manually. But you don't tell us what is the error and we have to understand your data model. Can you put a screenshot as @Joseph said ?

Comment: Can you show us the field calculator ? before clicking 'ok' even if it's gray

Comment: According to the field calculator screenshot, you have to : put your layer in edit mode, set a name to new field, set it to string

Comment: I have set it to edit mode. Then I selected the create a new field option if thats what you meant and have set it to string. The author column remains empty.

Comment: Is this from a **.csv file**? If so then you won't be able to make edits through the _Field Calculator_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't even need the field calculator

In the table view, not the field calculator start editing.
The new quick updater tool should appear
Select the author column from the drop down on the left 
In the blank box add your desired text in single quotes 'myname'
Click update all 
Done

or have I missed something?

Comment: That answered it.

Answer (score 3):

```
"Author" || 'example text'
```

You need single quotes round the text string.

Comment: Good to know: double quotes `"` are to reference fields, single quotes `'` are for pure string literals (text). Would be nice to see this in the answer so it explains a bit more background.